# Using DirectXHelper.h in DX11 application causes 'namespace/class not found' errors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx

I am trying to follow the DirectX 11 Tutorials found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/setting-up-directx-resources

But, I had to find DirectXHelper.h online. There are a few different versions, but this is the smallest one I found.

The problem is, when I try to compile with it included, I get errors like:

```
C2653   'Platform': is not a class or namespace name    
C3861   'CreateException': identifier not found     
C2039   'Storage': is not a member of 'Windows'     
C2871   'Storage': a namespace with this name does not exist    
C3083   'ApplicationModel': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type 
C3083   'Package': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type  
C2039   'Current': is not a member of 'Windows'     
C2065   'Current': undeclared identifier
```

I am not sure what to do or what I need to include. When I do a search for
Platform::Exception::CreateException(hr) I fidnit in 
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\VC\LIB\STORE\REFERENCES\PLATFORM.WINMD

I'm not sure how I am supposed to reference this.

```
//DirectXHelper.h
#pragma once

#include <ppltasks.h>   // For create_task

namespace DX
{
    inline void ThrowIfFailed(HRESULT hr)
    {
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // Set a breakpoint on this line to catch Win32 API errors.
            throw Platform::Exception::CreateException(hr);
        }
    }

    // Function that reads from a binary file asynchronously.
    inline Concurrency::task<std::vector<byte>> ReadDataAsync(const std::wstring& filename)
    {
        using namespace Windows::Storage;
        using namespace Concurrency;

        auto folder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;

        return create_task(folder->GetFileAsync(Platform::StringReference(filename.c_str()))).then([](StorageFile^ file)
        {
            return FileIO::ReadBufferAsync(file);
        }).then([](Streams::IBuffer^ fileBuffer) -> std::vector<byte>
        {
            std::vector<byte> returnBuffer;
            returnBuffer.resize(fileBuffer->Length);
            Streams::DataReader::FromBuffer(fileBuffer)->ReadBytes(Platform::ArrayReference<byte>(returnBuffer.data(), fileBuffer->Length));
            return returnBuffer;
        });
    }

    // Converts a length in device-independent pixels (DIPs) to a length in physical pixels.
    inline float ConvertDipsToPixels(float dips, float dpi)
    {
        static const float dipsPerInch = 96.0f;
        return floorf(dips * dpi / dipsPerInch + 0.5f); // Round to nearest integer.
    }
}
```

Note: I tried building this a as a Win32 Console App and Win32 App, same errors came up

Comment: That tutorial did not tell you how to get the project started from the correct project template.  Which is File > New > Project > Visual C++ > Windows > Universal > DirectX 11 App.   Sets up a bunch of stuff that avoids these compile errors.  And gives you DirectXHelper.h inside the Common folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of `ThrowIfFailed` is assuming you are building a UWP app using C++/CX (a.k.a. `/ZW`). That tutorial assumes you are using the DirectX 11 App template for the UWP platform on Windows 10 as your starting point.

You can write one that's more generic for C++ as (using `/EHsc`):

```
#include <exception>

namespace DX
{
    inline void ThrowIfFailed(HRESULT hr)
    {
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // Set a breakpoint on this line to catch DirectX API errors
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }
}
```

See [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) for more on this helper.

A version of the `ReadDataAsync` helper that works for Win32 desktop apps can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Microsoft/DirectXTK/ReadData.h).

`ConvertDipsToPixels` is only needed for UWP apps.

> You should take a look at *DirectX Tool Kit* [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) which supports Win32 desktop apps, UWP apps, Windows phone 8.x, and Xbox One XDK apps.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this, I am using DirectX toolkit, but I want to build a custom OBJ file -> mesh converter, and DXTK doesn't seem to offer functionality for building mesh from vertices and indices. Do you know if there is a way to do this without modifying source code for DXTK?

Comment: [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh) includes the ``meshconvert`` tool for doing simple conversions of Wavefront OBJ files to ``CMO``, ``SDKMESH``, and/or ``VBO``. Note I'm working on glTF2 support.